# Accessing Jar File Classes and Methods with ColdFusion

Tags: java, xml, jar, coldfusion

I have a jar file that when extracted has the following path

```
 xmlcreator.jar

 xmlcreator (folder)
     xmlpackage (folder)
         data1.class
         xxxx.class
             createxml (method)
```

If I create myObj1 like the following, I can view all the fields in data1 and field1 contains value1.

```
 <cfset myObj1 = createObject("java","xmlpackage.data1") />
 <cfset myObj1.field1 = "value1">
 <cfdump var="#myObj1#">
```

I would like to create the xml after populating all the fields in the data1 class.  The xxxx.class has the method createxml that creates the xml file however if I try the following it seems that createxml does not know about data1.

```
 <cfset myObj2 = createObject("java","xmlpackage.xxxx”) />
 <cfset myObj2.data1 = myobj1 />
 <cfset return = myObj2.createxml()>
```

The ColdFusion error simply returns data1 at the top of the error with no explanation.  So by creating the object xmlpackage.xxxx I can not seem to get to data1.

I do I get data into the data1 class and get xxxx.createxml to create the xml file?

**Update:**

Sorry for the confusion. I thought that keeping it simple was going to be easy. I have added the code, the dump of the object, and the stack trace of the error in order of what I am attempting to do.

```
<cfset myObj = createObject("java","CDAPackage.PatientRole") />
<cfset myObj.patientFamilyName = "Jones">
<cfdump var="#myObj#">

<cfset ccdaObj = createObject("java","CDAPackage.CCDA") />
<cfdump var="#ccdaObj#">
<cfset ccdaObj.PatientRole = myobj />
<cfset x = ccdaObj.GenerateCCDA()>
<cfdump var="#x#">
```

**Dump of myObj**

```
object of CDAPackage.PatientRole
Class Name  CDAPackage.PatientRole
Methods 
Method  Return Type
getRaceList()   java.util.List
setRaceList(java.util.List) void
Fields  
Field   Value
java.util.List RaceList [undefined value]
java.lang.String administrativeGenderCode   [undefined value]
java.lang.String administrativeGenderDisplayName    [undefined value]
CDAPackage.Address birthPlaceAddress    CDAPackage.Address
java.lang.String birthTime  [undefined value]
java.lang.String ethnicGroupCode    [undefined value]
java.lang.String ethnicGroupCodeDisplayName [undefined value]
java.lang.String insuranceProvider  [undefined value]
java.lang.String languageCommunication  [undefined value]
java.lang.String languageCommunicationDisplayname   [undefined value]
java.lang.String languageCommunicationModeCodeCode  [undefined value]
java.lang.String languageCommunicationModeCodeDisplayName   [undefined value]
java.lang.String languageCommunicationPreferenceInd [undefined value]
java.lang.String maritalStatusCode  [undefined value]
java.lang.String maritalStatusDisplayName   [undefined value]
java.lang.String mrn    [undefined value]
CDAPackage.Address patientAddress   CDAPackage.Address
java.lang.String patientFamilyName  Jones
... more fields
```

**Dump of ccdaObj**

```
object of CDAPackage.CCDA
Class Name  CDAPackage.CCDA
Methods 
Method  Return Type
GenerateCCDA()  java.lang.String
Fields  
Field   Value
java.lang.String CCDACode   [undefined value]
java.lang.String CCDADisplayName    [undefined value]
java.lang.String CCDAEffectiveTimeValue [undefined value]
java.lang.String Chiefcomplaint [undefined value]
java.lang.String DocumentID [undefined value]
java.lang.String EHRID  [undefined value]
java.lang.String EHRName    [undefined value]
CDAPackage.Address FacilityAddressObj   CDAPackage.Address
java.util.List FunctionalStatusListObj  java.util.List
CDAPackage.AssignedPerson PrimaryProviderObj    CDAPackage.AssignedPerson
java.util.List ReferralListObj  java.util.List
java.util.List allergyListObj   java.util.List
java.util.List carePlanListObj  java.util.List
java.util.List careTeamObj  java.util.List
java.lang.String dischargeinstructions  [undefined value]
java.util.List encounterDiagnosisListObj    java.util.List
java.util.List encounterListObj java.util.List
java.util.List immunizationListObj  java.util.List
java.util.List instructionListObj   [undefined value]
java.util.List medicationAdministedListObj  java.util.List
java.util.List medicationListObj    java.util.List
CDAPackage.PatientRole patientRoleObj   CDAPackage.PatientRole
... more fields
```

**Stack Trace**

```
 java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: PATIENTROLE
     at coldfusion.runtime.StructBean.bindName(StructBean.java:243)
     at coldfusion.runtime.Scope.put(Scope.java:74)
     at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._arrayset(CfJspPage.java:1093)
     at     coldfusion.runtime.NeoPageContext.SymTab_setSplitNameInMap(NeoPageContext.java:1429)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._structSetAt(CfJspPage.java:2356)
at cfdllcall2ecfm1400054296.runPage(/Applications/ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/test/dllcall.cfm:16)
at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246)
at ...
```

Comment: Java object errors are typically found in the stack trace. Can you please post the full stack trace? Also, check the CF error logs. Does this jar have a public API?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the API, but I suspect this syntax `myObj1.field1 = "value1"` is not actually setting the "field" value as you expect. [Per the docs](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Using+Java+objects), that syntax is only supported if a) *"..the class exposes the ["fields"] as public properties..."* OR b) the properties are not public, but the object *"...is a JavaBean that provides public getter and setter methods of the form get_PropertyName_() and set_PropertyName_(value)..."*.

Comment: I added the stack trace.

Comment: I added the dump of myObj1

Comment: (Edit) Is there a public API?  The rules about setting properties apply to both classes. It is difficult to tell what PATIENTROLE corresponds to in your simplified example. Which object is throwing the error? Line numbers are not always exact, but the trace suggests it is around line 16 /Applications/ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/test/dllcall.cfm:16.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I thought that keeping it simple was going to be easy.  I have added the code, the dump of the object, and the stack trace of the error in order of what I am attempting to do.  Trying to create an object with data then create the xml with the data.  A third party created the jar and I am trying to determine if there needs to be a change for ColdFusion to use it.

Comment: No worries. Sometimes keeping it simple is works. Not so much with custom classes. From the dump, it looks like the field name is "patientRoleObj", not "patientRole".  (Hard to tell if the field is public or not. You would have to look at the API docs).  Try using: object.patientRole*Obj* = yourPatientRoleObject.

Comment: That did it.  I now have a better understanding of what is happening in the jar file.  This line PatientRole patientRoleObj in the ccda.java file is assigning all the fields from the PatienRole class to that object. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(From comments)

> `java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: PATIENTROLE`

Looking at the fields in the dump, it looks like the field you are trying to set is named is `patientRoleObj`, rather than `patientRole`. Try using that field name instead:

```
<cfset yourOtherObject.patientRoleObj = yourPatientRoleObject />
```